# How to input a file and export it as a copy?

Tags: python, function, copy, xls

I have a file (a xls file) that I want to copy and with that copy I want to make two other xls files off of it. Is shutil good to use for this or is there something else. I want to write a function to copy and delete but I'm new to python.

Comment: For simple file copying, `shutil` is the right place to look. For deletion: `os.remove`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
import shutil
import os

# Copy a file
shutil.copy("original.xlsx", "duplicate.xlsx")
# Delete a file
os.remove("duplicate.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is safer if you MOVE the first file after creating the first copy, so you do not accidentially delete it if your program couldn't write to either of the files correctly.
It is also twice as fast

```
import shutil
shutil.copy("c:\\temp\\searchme.png","c:\\temp\\searchme2.png")
shutil.move("c:\\temp\\searchme.png","c:\\temp\\searchme3.png")
```

The double backslashes are necessary to make python process the directory